# UINavigationBar right button selection

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I would like to know how to stop the right bar button from being selectable until the user has for-filled obligations.

I currently set up my right barbutton like this

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Search" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(submitSearch)];
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setStyle:UIControlStateDisabled];

And although it looks non selectable because I have set setstyle as disabled it is still selectable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setEnabled:NO]
```

Comment: worked perfectly.. thanks for that! will mark once time is up.